# Convert YYYY/MM/DD format date data in file to DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: date, sed

Quick helpful sed to convert YYYY/MM/DD format date data in file to DD.MM.YYYY

```
sed 's|\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-1][0-9]\)/\([0-3][0-9]\)|\3.\2.\1|g' date.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain your question ?

Comment: It's OK if you ask a question and provide your own answer but not to provide answer without a question [read instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to "share" a snippet the OP found helpful. Which may be a reasonable thing to want to do (though I don't think it is in this case) but this isn't the way to do that. The way to do that is to write up a canonical question to which the snippet is the correct answer and to then answer it and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
sed 's|\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-1][0-9]\)/\([0-3][0-9]\)|\3.\2.\1|g' date.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if using a GNU sed, some minor modification for a better date pattern filtering

```
sed 's#\b\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\(0[1-9]\|1[0-2]\)/\(0[1-9]\|[1-2][0-9]\|3[01]\)\b#\3.\2.\1#g' date.txt
```